# Node.js HTTP agent pre establish tcp connection

Tags: node.js, http, tcp

So I'm working on an application where there are a lot of network requests to be sent and so I have set up an http agent to reuse tcp connections like so, which would be used all over my application :

```
const https = require("https");
global.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    keepAlive: true,
})
```

This will allow me to reuse tcp sockets that have already been created so I don't have to create them again and save time when dealing with lots of http requests. But before I send any http requests there will not be any tcp connections. So the first time I send an http request I have to wait till the tcp connection is established. Is there a way to tell the https agent to maintain a minimum number of free tcp sockets to a domain at all times ? Right now when my applications starts up I'm just sending meaningless http requests so that the tcp connections are established and kept-alive like so :

```
function establishTcpConns(numConns) {
    let arr = [];

    for(let i=0; i<numConns; i++) {
        arr.push(
            // fetch is imported like so : const fetch = require("node-fetch");
            fetch("https://example.com", {
                agent: url => global.httpsAgent,
                headers: {
                   "connection": "keep-alive"
                }
            })
        );
    }

    return Promise.allSettled(arr);
}
```

I see that there a function called `agent.createConnection(options[, callback])` defined in the nodejs docs https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#agentcreateconnectionoptions-callback
Is this what I'm looking for? If so how would I use it?

Comment: I think that you have a misunderstanding here. HTTP keep-alive does not mandate client or server to keep the TCP connection open but just basically says that the other site supports multiple requests over the same connection. Both client and server can close this TCP connection at any time after a request was done. Thus you cannot rely on the connection being open.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Well I can certainly open up new tcp connections to the server waiting to be used right? Any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: There should not be any need to explicitly open a TCP connection. `fetch` will do everything necessary by its own, i.e. create a new TCP connection if needed, reuse an existing one if possible.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yea the first time it makes an http connection there won't be any tcp connections. I want to create it beforehand so there is no time waste. I know it won't take much time to create it but in my case this small time matters.

Comment: *"but in my case this small time matters."* - then HTTP might be the wrong protocol for the job in the first place. Plain TCP or Websockets might be better suited. Anyway, you can open the connection by doing a minimal request. But you cannot rely on the TCP connection staying open for further requests.